# Problems connecting nodemcu esp8266 on my laptop

Tags: esp8266, usb, stm32

I have a new laptop and didn't run any development boards on it except some Arduino boards.

But now, I have only nodemcu esp8266 and maple mini boards and trying to connect them but I get error connection message.

`esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header`

I tried to find solutions but apparently I'm stuck here and I can't do anything.

I tried to re-flash the nodemcu with the flasher but I can't get the addresses. This is what I got:

[image]

The flashing started but can't get the AP MAC and STA MAC. I don't know what is the problem now, I used to flash it before but on my old Dell laptop. I started to think that there are some problems with usb ports of my msi gaming laptop, they are 3.0, I think that could be a problem.

The board is recognized in device manager and in Arduino IDE COM ports.

My question is how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have a problem connecting my dev boards with Arduino IDE. I don't know if it's a hardware or software problem.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Is the correct USB-to-Serial port driver installed correctly on your laptop? Do you use the correct COM port and the correct settings (baud rate, SPI mode) in the Flasher?

Comment: @StarCat Yep, I configured all these stuff, same COM ports and same baud rate. The driver is installed by default. I deleted it and installed it again. Same problem ! Really strange, it's working perfectly on my desktop which is not around right now.